# Voltage Buffer without power supply

Tags: design

Is there a circuit or an ic chip which can buffer the voltage without any external dc power supply being supplied to it?

Comment: Capacitor I guess?

Comment: What do you mean by "buffer"?

Comment: Voltage follower to prevent loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffering means producing the same signal voltage with a higher available current.

If you have no power supply to your circuit, you have nowhere for the extra current in your 'buffered' output to come from.

You don't buffer power supply rails. You might design a power supply rail that tracks the voltage level of another power supply rail but you won't see that very often.

Comment: i need a voltage follower to prevent loading

Comment: @Code, can you supply power to the buffer circuit that you need?

Comment: i do not want to supply external power suppply. With power supply a simple op amp would do

Comment: @Code, then no power means no buffer, as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you by "buffer" mean "replicate the voltage with lower output resistance" then no. The output power of such a buffer would regularily be higher than the input power which means it's not possible. Even replicating the signal at the same power (to isolate different stages) isn't possible because there will always be internal losses.